Run multiple SQL UPDATE strings using VBA but getting error
I've spent the weekend scouring Stack Overflow for an answer and I can't find one that addresses my specific issue.   Below is the SQL string of a simple Update query.   I have ten of these separate queries.  I can easily use VBA to run each query in succession, and that works great.  BUT, I would prefer to run them using RunSQL so I don't have to have 10 separate queries to manage.  I took the SQL string from the Query Designer and pasted it to the following VBA:
Dim sql As String
sql = "UPDATE Comments LEFT JOIN KeysFound ON Comments.[Survey#] = KeysFound.[survey#] _
SET KeysFound.Lost = -1, KeysFound.[survey#] = [Comments].[survey#] _
WHERE (((Comments.Comment) Like " * Lost * "))"
DoCmd.RunSQL (sql)

Here's what happens:
screenshot of sql string and error

Screenshot of simple Query Design

I removed line breaks; still error.   I added a semi-colon to end and still error.   I thought running the simple SQL statement from the Query Designer would not error out.
The goal is to run 10 of these statements under one VBA Procedure so I don't carry 10 separate queries.  The only thing that changes in the SQL statement is the Like "Lost"   The word Lost will be replaced with "Unhappy" and then replaced with "slow" and so on.  Then the UPDATE statement simply updates the associated row in the joined table with a -1 in the "Yes/No" field when the word is found in the comments.
This works great using separate queries and running them in sequence with the Docmd.openquery, but that's not the goal.
Result of array
Result for field.lost; need to change to next el

Good result


Your sql construction is off - see suggestions below
Dim sql As String, el
For Each el in Array("Lost", "Unhappy", "slow") 'loop search terms
    sql = "UPDATE Comments LEFT JOIN KeysFound ON Comments.[Survey#] = KeysFound.[survey#] " & _
          " SET KeysFound." & el & " = -1, KeysFound.[survey#] = [Comments].[survey#] " & _
          " WHERE Comments.Comment Like '*" & el & "*'"
    DoCmd.RunSQL sql
Next el


Tim, thanks I'll give it a try in a few.   Have to run out then be back.   I didn't think I could do an array, but that may do the trick.

Tim, functionally worked great.  I forgot to mention: in "SET KeysFound.Lost = -1, KeysFound.[survey#] = [Comments].[survey#]" the word lost would need to change to each el.   Do I need to qualify "el" after the decimal?

Sorry, I'm not understanding the question.  Where/what is the "decimal"?

Apologies.  I mean "dot"  In SET KeysFound.lost, the word "lost" after the dot would change to the next word in the array, too.   See the image of the result.   A check should show up in the "slow" column when el changes to "slow"

It looks like all I have to do is change the word "lost" to the variable of the array "el"  Then it should loop fine, and store the data in the associated field name of the current array value.    I don't know how to qualify it so it doesn't think the array variable is a field name.

OK I see - I missed that other "Lost".  Check the edit above.

Tim,  it works perfectly now!   See last image.    I will cascade that out to the other fields to populate.   (This is used to do a keyword search from a survey field and then count how many surveys say "lost" or "slow"  etc.    I keep the list of attributes in a table, but I think it would be too complex to try to have the array read the Table value.   Adding them into the VBA array variable is easy enough.    THANK YOU TIM!   You made my day.   Dave

Consider refactoring your SQL to use IIF() for a single SQL query. Below also uses table aliases and the ALIKE operator so query run in Access frontend UI or Access backend ODBC.
UPDATE Comments c LEFT JOIN KeysFound k ON c.[Survey#] = k.[survey#]
SET 
   k.Lost = IIF(c.Comment ALIKE '% Lost %', -1, k.Lost),
   k.[survey#] = IIF(c.Comment ALIKE '% Lost %', c.[survey#], k.[survey#]),

   k.great = IIF(c.Comment ALIKE '% great %', -1, k.Lost),
   k.[survey#] = IIF(c.Comment ALIKE '% great %', c.[survey#], k.[survey#]),

   k.slow = IIF(c.Comment ALIKE '% slow %', -1, k.Lost),
   k.[survey#] = IIF(c.Comment ALIKE '% slow %', c.[survey#], k.[survey#]) 
   ...


Aside: Reconsider this database design for efficient storage and less complex or tedious queries. Specifically, avoid storing data elements as columns in a table but as rows such as below suggestion with table names void of special characters or mixed cases:



survey_number
keyword_value
keyword_selected




1
lost
-1


1
great
0


1
slow
0


3
lost
0


3
great
0


3
slow
-1



Rows always scale better in relational databases then columns. MS Access has no limits on rows but does have a 255 column limit.

You know, that is a great recommendation.  I didn't like having to add a "field" just to have a place to store the Yes or No from the word search.   I can still use the table as the basis for a report/query of the findings per month since I simply join Survey_number back to the other tables.    I'll give it a whirl.   Now, if I can simply read the value from the table of values (lost, slow, missed, etc.) I wouldn't have to type them in.   BUT this is great progress!

Parfait,  I interpret the above to mean change the table of K to just have 3 fields:  Survey_num, K_value, and K_selected.   The SQL no longer loops and will just store the values based upon the evaluation of the IIF?   If I'm reading that correctly.

Sorry, Parfait.   I love your approach, but I couldn't get it to work in the new DB structure you suggest above.   For now I guess I'll have to stick with the horizontal layout until I can resolve the code....   Here's how I modified it:  Dim sql As String
sql = "UPDATE Comments c LEFT JOIN Keytest k ON c.[Survey#] = k.[surveynum] " & _
" SET k.[kselected] = IIF(c.Comment ALIKE '% Lost %', -1, 0), " & _
" k.[surveynum] = IIF(c.Comment ALIKE '% Lost %', c.[survey#], k.[surveynum]), " & _
" k.[kvalue] = 'Lost'"

You'll have to restructure other tables and rewrite the update query with a nested IIF without any loop. Again, just an aside suggestion but heed good database design early on and avoid challenges later on! Also, if using this UPDATE solution
save the single query and call it with DoCmd.OpenQuery and avoid messy VBA concatenation. Happy coding!

Parfait,  I thank you very much for following up.   This survey analysis of keywords is a missing link; nobody takes the time to assess the customer.  So, now with it automated, I bring the horse to water.   (I will adjust the DB, and hear you loud and clear)  Thanks again!!  Dave
